# Не получается расшифровать файл методом RSA

Tags: c#, шифрование, rsa

Имеется класс для шифрования и расшифровки файлов через метод RSA.

```
public class Files
{
    public static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            RSAParameters publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
            rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);

            using (var fstreamIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var fstreamOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[64];
                for (; ; )
                {
                    int bytesRead = fstreamIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    byte[] encrypted = bytesRead.Equals(buf.Length) ? rsa.Encrypt(buf, true) : rsa.Encrypt(buf.Take(bytesRead).ToArray(), true);
                    fstreamOut.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            RSAParameters privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
            rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);

            using (var fstreamIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var fstreamOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[128];
                for (; ; )
                {
                    int bytesRead = fstreamIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(buf, true);
                    fstreamOut.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При расшифровки получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка при декодировании заполнения OAEP.

Что это значит и как исправить?

И подскажите пожалуйста на счёт

`RSAParameters publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
 rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);`

Для чего нужны эти параметры и где взять публичный и закрытый ключ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя реализация RSA.

***Main:***

```
namespace RSA
{
    class Program
    {
        const int maxPrimeNumbers = 10000;
        private static FileHandler _mFileHandler = new FileHandler();
        private static RSAHandler _mRsaHandler = new RSAHandler(maxPrimeNumbers);

        static void Main()
        {
            int caseSwitch;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Зашифровать файл");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Расшифровать файл");
                Console.WriteLine("0 - Выход");

                Console.Write("Выбирите метод: ");
                caseSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                string strFile = InputFileName();
                byte[] nArFile;

                switch (caseSwitch)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFile)) &&
                            _mFileHandler.TryReadFileByteWise(strFile, out nArFile))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Показать файл побайтово? <Y / AnyKey>");

                            ConsoleKey ck = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                            if (ck == ConsoleKey.Y) ShowInput(nArFile);

                            HandleEncryption(nArFile, strFile);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFile)) &&
                            _mFileHandler.TryReadFileByteWise(strFile, out nArFile))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Показать файл побайтово? <Y / AnyKey>");

                            ConsoleKey ck = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                            if (ck == ConsoleKey.Y) ShowInput(nArFile);

                            HandleDecryption(nArFile, strFile);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 0:
                        Console.Write("До свидания!");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Выбран не известный метод!");
                        break;
                }
            } while (caseSwitch != 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Обрабатывает ввод необходимых данных для шифрования сообщения. Запускает шифрование, если ввод действителен.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nArMessage">Открытый текст, который будет зашифрован.</param> 
        /// <param name="strFile">Оригинальное имя файла. При записи зашифрованного файла он будет использоваться в качестве префикса(Test.txt-->Test_Encrypted.txt)</param>
        private static void HandleEncryption(byte[] nArMessage, string strFile)
        {
            int[] nArCypher;
            int nPrime1 = InputPrimeNumber();
            if (nPrime1 > 0)
            {
                int nPrime2 = InputPrimeNumber();
                if (nPrime2 > 0)
                {
                    int nN;
                    int nD;
                    nArCypher = _mRsaHandler.Encrypt(nArMessage, nPrime1, nPrime2, out nN, out nD);

                    Console.WriteLine("Показать зашифрованный файл побайтно? <Y / AnyKey>");
                    ConsoleKey ck = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                    if (ck == ConsoleKey.Y) ShowInput(nArCypher);

                    Console.WriteLine($"\nШифрование сделано. n={nN}  d={nD}");
                    string strNewKeyFile = _mFileHandler.GetNewFileName(strFile, "_Key");
                    try
                    {
                        _mFileHandler.WriteFile(strNewKeyFile, nN, nD);
                        Console.WriteLine("Файл с ключами записан: " + strNewKeyFile);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при записи зашифрованного файла: " + strNewKeyFile);
                    }

                    string strNewFile = _mFileHandler.GetNewKeyFileName(strFile, "_Encrypted");
                    try
                    {
                        _mFileHandler.WriteFile(strNewFile, nArCypher);
                        Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованный файл записан: " + strNewFile);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при записи зашифрованного файла: " + strNewFile);
                    }

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Отменено!");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Отменено!");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Обрабатывает ввод необходимых данных для расшифровки сообщения. Запускает расшифровку, если ввод действителен.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nArCypher"> Открытый текст, который будет расшифрованн.</param>
        /// <param name="strFile">Оригинальное имя файла. При записи расшифрованного файла он будет использоваться в качестве префикса(Test.txt-->Test_Decrypted.txt)</param>
        private static void HandleDecryption(byte[] nArCypher, string strFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nОткрытый ключ n");
            int nN = InputNumber();
            byte[] nArMessage;
            if (nN > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nОткрытый ключ d");
                int nD = InputNumber();
                if (nD > 0)
                {
                    nArMessage = _mRsaHandler.Decrypt(nArCypher, nN, nD);
                    if (nArMessage != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Показать расшифрованный файл побайтно? <Y / AnyKey>");
                        ConsoleKey ck = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                        if (ck == ConsoleKey.Y) ShowInput(nArMessage);

                        string strNewFile = _mFileHandler.GetNewFileName(strFile, "_Decrypted");
                        try
                        {
                            _mFileHandler.WriteFile(strNewFile, nArMessage);
                            Console.WriteLine("\nРасшифрованный файл записан: " + strNewFile);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при записи расшифрованного файла: " + strNewFile);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при расшифровке файла: \n" + strFile +
                                          "\nЭто не зашифрованный файл. \nНажмите любую клавишу, чтобы вернуться к основному методу.");
                    }

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Отменено!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Отменено!");
            }
        }

        // Показать массив в типе int
        private static void ShowInput(int[] nAr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var t in nAr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString().PadLeft(3, ' '));
            }
        }


        //Показать байтовый массив побайтно в двоичном, десятичном, шестнадцатеричном и графическом представлении.
        private static void ShowInput(byte[] nAr)
        {
            string[] strOutputAsHex =
                (BitConverter.ToString(nAr)).Split('-');
            Console.WriteLine("");
            for (int i = 0; i < nAr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{Convert.ToString(nAr[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0')}, {nAr[i].ToString().PadLeft(3)}, {strOutputAsHex[i]}, {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[1] {nAr[i]})}");
            }
        }

        //Обрабатывает ввод простого числа.
        private static int InputPrimeNumber()
        {
            int nRet = 0;
            int nCur = 0;
            string strCur;
            bool blnIsValid = false;
            bool blnExit = false;
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            while (!blnIsValid && !blnExit)
            {
                Console.Write($"Введите простое число от 0 до {maxPrimeNumbers}: ");
                strCur = Console.ReadLine();
                if (strCur.ToLower() == "cancel") blnExit = true;
                else if (Int32.TryParse(strCur, out nCur))
                {
                    if (_mRsaHandler.IsPrimeNumber(nCur))
                    {
                        nRet = nCur;
                        blnIsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine($"Это не простое число. Введите простое число от 0 до {maxPrimeNumbers}: " + strCur);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели не чилсо. Введите простое число от 0 до {maxPrimeNumbers}: " + strCur);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите \"cancel\", чтобы вернуться в главное меню");
                }
            }

            return nRet;
        }

        // Обрабатывает ввод числа.
        private static int InputNumber()
        {
            int nRet = 0;
            int nCur = 0;
            string strCur;
            bool blnIsValid = false;
            bool blnExit = false;
            while (!blnIsValid && !blnExit)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите правильный ключ: ");
                strCur = Console.ReadLine();
                if (strCur != null && strCur.ToLower() == "cancel") blnExit = true;
                else if (Int32.TryParse(strCur, out nCur))
                {
                    nRet = nCur;
                    blnIsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Недействительный ключ: " + strCur);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите \"cancel\", чтобы вернуться в главное меню");
                }
            }

            return nRet;
        }

        //Обрабатывает ввод действительного (существующего) имени файла
        private static string InputFileName()
        {
            string strRet = String.Empty;
            string strCur;
            bool blnIsValid = false;
            bool blnExit = false;
            string strPath = new FileInfo(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
                .Directory?.FullName;

            while (!blnIsValid && !blnExit)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите путь к файлу: ");
                strCur = Console.ReadLine();
                if (strCur != null && strCur.ToLower() == "cancel") blnExit = true;
                else if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(strPath, strCur)))
                {
                    strRet = Path.Combine(strPath, strCur);
                    blnIsValid = true;
                }
                else if (File.Exists(strCur))
                {
                    strRet = strCur;
                    blnIsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл поврежден: " + strCur);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите \"cancel\", чтобы вернуться в главное меню");
                }
            }

            return strRet;
        }
    }
}
```

***RSA:***

```
namespace RSA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Содержит все необходимые методы для шифрования в byte[] через RSA
    /// </summary>
    public class RSAHandler
    {
        //Массив всех простых чисел от 3 до nMax (устанавливается в ctor)
        private int[] _mArPrimeNums;

        /// <summary>
        /// Нахождение всех необходимых простых чисел
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nMax">Верхняя граница для простых чисел</param>
        public RSAHandler(int nMax)
        {
            _mArPrimeNums = SieveOfErathostenes(nMax);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Шифрует через RSA
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nArMessage">Сообщение для шифрования</param>
        /// <param name="nPrime1">Простое число 1</param>
        /// <param name="nPrime2">Простое число 2</param>
        /// <param name="nN">OUT n будет рассчитываться по методу</param>
        /// <param name="nD">OUT d будет рассчитываться по методу</param>
        /// <returns>Шифротекст</returns>
        public int[] Encrypt(byte[] nArMessage, int nPrime1, int nPrime2, out int nN, out int nD)
        {
            int[] nArCypher = new Int32[nArMessage.Length];

            nN = nPrime1 * nPrime2; //N = P * Q
            int nPhiOfN = (nPrime1 - 1) * (nPrime2 - 1); //Fi = (P-1)*(Q-1)
            int nE = GetRelativelyPrime(nPhiOfN); //E

            nD = modInverse(nE, nPhiOfN); //D

            for (int i = 0; i < nArMessage.Length; i++)
            {
                int nM = nArMessage[i]; //M = D(c)
                Int32 nCypher = (Int32) BigInteger.ModPow(nM, nE, nN); //M ^ E % N 
                nArCypher[i] = nCypher; //запись в массив
            }

            return nArCypher;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Расшифровывает через RSA
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nArCypher">Зашифрованный текст для расшифровки</param>
        /// <param name="nN">n</param>
        /// <param name="nD">d</param>
        /// <returns>Простой текст</returns>
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] nArCypher, int nN, int nD)
        {
            int[] nIntAr = ByteArToIntAr(nArCypher);
            byte[] nArMessage = null;
            if (nIntAr != null)
            {
                nArMessage = new byte[nIntAr.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < nIntAr.Length; i++)
                {
                    int nCur = (Int32) BigInteger.ModPow(nIntAr[i], nD, nN); //M ^ D % N 
                    nArMessage[i] = Convert.ToByte( nCur % 256); //%255 необходимо из-за попытки расшифровки с неправильными ключами nCur (E) может быть выше 255 - переполнение
                }
            }
            return nArMessage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// База экспоненциальной мощности
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nBase">База</param>
        /// <param name="nE">Экспонент</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private long Pow(int nBase, int nE)
        {
            long nRet = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(nE); i++)
            {
                nRet *= nBase;
            }

            return nRet;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Проверяет, является ли nCur (E) основным номером.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="potentialPn">Номер для проверки</param>
        /// <returns>истина, когда потенциал PN - простое число</returns>
        public bool IsPrimeNumber(int potentialPn)
        {
            return _mArPrimeNums.Contains(potentialPn);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Возвращает число, которое относительно просто для nCur. (E)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nCur">Относительно простое число, которое не имеет отношение к E</param>
        /// <returns>Относительно простое число для nCur</returns>
        private int GetRelativelyPrime(int nCur)
        {
            int nE = 0;
            bool blnFound = false;

            //Поиски, начинающиеся с 3 для действительно простого nCur (E). Останавливает поиск, когда он был найден.
            for (int i = 3; (i < (nCur / 2)) && (!blnFound); i++)
            {
                int nGgt = ggT(i, nCur);
                if (nGgt == 1)
                {
                    blnFound = true;
                    nE = i;
                }
            }
            return nE;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Найти общий делитель Greates для n1 и n2 (P и Q). Итеративное решение.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="n1">Номер один (P)</param>
        /// <param name="n2">Номер два (Q)</param>
        /// <returns>Решетки общего делителя n1 и n2 (P и Q)</returns>
        private int ggT(int n1, int n2)
        {
            n1 = (n1 < 0) ? n1 * (-1) : n1; //абсолютный          

            while (n2 > 0)
            {
                var nRet = n1 % n2;
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = nRet;
            }

            return n1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Модульный обратный (инверсия P и Q)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="n1">Номер один (P)</param>
        /// <param name="n2">Номер два (Q)</param>
        /// <returns>Модульная обратная n1 и n2 (инверсия P и Q)</returns>
        int modInverse(int n1, int n2)
        {
            int n3 = n2;
            int n4 = 0;
            int n5 = 1;
            while (n1 > 0)
            {
                int n6 = n3 / n1;
                int nLastN1 = n1;
                n1 = n3 % nLastN1;
                n3 = nLastN1;
                int nLastN5 = n5;
                n5 = n4 - n6 * nLastN5;
                n4 = nLastN5;
            }

            n4 %= n2;
            n4 = (n4 < 0) ? (n4 + n2) % n2 : n4;
            return n4;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Использует сито Erathostenes, чтобы найти простые числа до nMax.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nMax"></param> Максимальное простое число.
        /// <returns>Все простые чила начиная с 3 до nMax</returns>
        private int[] SieveOfErathostenes(int nMax)
        {
            int[] nArRet;
            bool[] blnArAnalysed = new bool[nMax + 1]; //Карта всех чисел которые не яв-вл простыми

            for (int i = 2; i < Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(nMax)); i++)
            {
                if (!blnArAnalysed[i])
                {
                    int j = i;
                    while (j * i <= nMax)
                    {
                        blnArAnalysed[j * i] = true;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Generate nArRet
            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 3; i < blnArAnalysed.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!blnArAnalysed[i]) l.Add(i);
            }
            nArRet = l.ToArray<int>();
            return nArRet;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Конверт из int[] в byte[]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intAr">Int-Array</param>
        /// <returns>Byte-Array</returns>
        public byte[] IntArToByteAr(int[] intAr)
        {
            byte[] nByteAr = new byte[intAr.Length * 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < intAr.Length; i++)
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(intAr[i]), 0, nByteAr, 4 * i, 4);
            return nByteAr;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Конверт из byte[] в int[]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nByteAr">Byte-Array</param>
        /// <returns>Int-Array</returns>
        public int[] ByteArToIntAr(byte[] nByteAr)
        {
            int[] nIntAr = new int[nByteAr.Length / 4];
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nByteAr.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    nIntAr[i / 4] = BitConverter.ToInt32(nByteAr, i);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Error in bitconverter
                nIntAr = null;
            }

            return nIntAr;
        }
    }
}
```

***File:***

```
namespace RSA
{
    public class FileHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Пытается прочитать файл побайтно и возвращает успех. Считанный файл записывается в переменную out.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strFileName"></param> файл для чтения
        /// <param name="nArFile"></param> OUT - возращает файл
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool TryReadFileByteWise(string strFileName, out byte[] nArFile)
        {
            bool blnSuccess = false;
            nArFile = new byte[0];

            try
            {
                nArFile = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileName);
                blnSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return blnSuccess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записывает байтовый массив в файл
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strFileName">Целевое имя файла</param>
        /// <param name="nArFile">Файл для записи</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        public bool WriteFile(string strFileName, byte[] nArFile)
        {
            bool blnSuccess = false;
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(strFileName, nArFile);
                blnSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return blnSuccess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записывает ключи в файл
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strFileName">Целевое имя файла</param>
        /// <param name="keyN">Ключ N для записи</param>
        /// /// <param name="keyD">Ключ D для записи</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        public bool WriteFile(string strFileName, int keyN, int keyD)
        {
            string keys = "N = " + keyN + " D = " + keyD;

            bool blnSuccess = false;
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(strFileName, keys);
                blnSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return blnSuccess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записывает массив int преобразуя в байтовый массив в файл
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strNewFile">Целевое имя файла</param>
        /// <param name="nIntAr">Массив для записи в файл</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool WriteFile(string strNewFile, int[] nIntAr)
        {
            byte[] nByteAr = IntArToByteAr(nIntAr);
            return WriteFile(strNewFile, nByteAr);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавляет постфикс к существующему имени файла, сохраняя путь и расширение
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strFile">оригинальное имя файла</param>
        /// <param name="strPostfix">постфикс</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetNewFileName(string strFile, string strPostfix)
        {
            string strPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFile);
            string strBlankFIle = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile);
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFile);
            string strNewFile = strBlankFIle + strPostfix + strExtension;
            if (strPath != null) strNewFile = Path.Combine(strPath, strNewFile);
            return strNewFile;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Добавляет постфикс к существующему имени файла, сохраняя путь и расширение
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strFile">оригинальное имя файла</param>
        /// <param name="strPostfix">постфикс</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetNewKeyFileName(string strFile, string strPostfix)
        {
            string strPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFile);
            string strBlankFIle = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile);
            string strNewFile = strBlankFIle + strPostfix + ".txt";
            if (strPath != null) strNewFile = Path.Combine(strPath, strNewFile);
            return strNewFile;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записывает байтовый массив в файл
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intAr">Int-Array для преобразования</param>
        /// <returns>Байт-массив</returns>
        public byte[] IntArToByteAr(int[] intAr)
        {
            byte[] nByteAr = new byte[intAr.Length * 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < intAr.Length; i++)
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(intAr[i]), 0, nByteAr, 4 * i, 4);
            return nByteAr;
        }
    }
}
```